# Join two tables on differently typed date columns in SQLAlchemy (Date vs. YYYYMMDD)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Title says it all.  I have two tables that each have a date column.  One has it's date stored as SQL Date object while the other uses an integer date (eg. 20150617).  I'm trying to define a SQLAlchemy relationship between the two but I'm not sure how to do the conversion before the join.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: You should look into using a hybrid property or a column_property. Implementation of these is going to depend on your db since date functions are variable. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#sql-expressions-as-mapped-attributes

Comment: Also: do you want a real sqlalchemy relationship between two models, or do you need only a join for the query?

Comment: @van, I'm using Microsoft SQL server and do need an actual relationship.

Comment: @Spencer, I completely forgot about hybrid properties, I'll try that out.

Comment: Which side is the foreign key in this relationship: integer or date?

Comment: @van, In this case neither is an actual foreign key.

Comment: I see. However this is important to know if you use `relationship` in order to add related objects. and if you just use *relationship* to query, then why do you need relationship and not just define a join condition in a query.